# set of closed points is dense in Spec $A$

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-geometry, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I have a question regarding the above topic.
Let $k$ be a (not neccesarily algebraically closed) field, $A$ a finitely generated $k$-Algebra. Show that the set of the closed points is dense in Spec $A$.

So far I have got the following. I was not quite sure, how to use the fact, that $A$ is a finitely generated $k$-Algebra.

But we know that the closed points in $A$ are the maximal ideals. Any topological space is the union of its irreducible components. So we have Spec $A = \bigcup_{i} U_i$ for some closed, irreducible subsets $U_i$. Each $U_i$ has a unique generic point $\mathfrak p_i$, so that $\overline{\{\mathfrak p_i\}} = U_i$. Now, since $A$ is a finitely generated $k$-Algebra, we have for any prime ideal $\mathfrak p$:
$$\mathfrak p = \bigcap_{\mathfrak m \supset \mathfrak p} \mathfrak m,$$
where $\mathfrak m$ is a maximal ideal. So it follows, that 
$$ \text{Spec }A = \bigcup_i U_i = \bigcup_i \overline{\{\mathfrak p_i\}} = \bigcup_i \overline{\left(\{\bigcap_{\mathfrak m \supset \mathfrak p} \mathfrak m\}\right)_i} = \overline{\bigcup_i \left(\{\bigcap_{\mathfrak m \supset \mathfrak p} \mathfrak m\}\right)_i}$$
So it follows, that the closure of the set of maximal ideal equals Spec $A$.

I would appreciate any comments, where the proof is mistaken and what a correct proof would look like.

Comment: "it follows": it doesn't, at least not without a few words of explanation. What about the following thought : if $x\in A$ is not a unit, then $x$ belongs to some maximal ideal ?

Comment: Alright. Then how does it follow, if it does?

Comment: You must use @[name of the user] so that the user in question gets notified. If someone comments below the post then op will always get notified but not other users. I thought you are new here and didn't know this.